# How to get the maximum count, and ID from the table SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, querying

```
**castID**
nm0000116
nm0000116
nm0000116
nm0000116
nm0000116
nm0634240
nm0634240
nm0798899
```

This is my table (created as a view). Now I want to list the castID which has the most count (in this case which is nm0000116, and how many occurences/count it has in this table ( should be 5 times) and I'm not quite sure which query to use

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem by providing the code you've tried. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  MAX(E),
  castId
FROM 
 (SELECT COUNT(castId) AS E,castId FROM [directors winning movies list] GROUP BY castId) AS t
```

Comment: This is what I have entered: SELECT 
  MAX(E),
  castID 
FROM 
 (SELECT COUNT(caseID),castID AS E FROM `directors winning movies list` GROUP BY castID)

BUUTT I get MySQL said: 

#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: Yes, have used quotation marks, #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: Now I get an error #1054 - Unknown column 't.castID' in 'field list'

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'castID' in 'field list' is still persisting

Comment: @user3601148 : My bad, assigned alias to another field.Check updated.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
Select CastId, count(*) countOfCastId
From table 
Group By CastId
Having count(*)
    = (Select Max(cnt)
       From (Select count(*) cnt
             From table
             Group By CastId) z)
```

Comment: heeyy thanks for that, could you tell me how I would be able to get the count too for the castID that is selected?

Comment: Yeah, just include `count(*)` in Select clause... I edited query.

Comment: I've been trying to create a view, but it's giving me an error: #1349 views slect contains a subquery in the from clause, do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You could just return the topmost count using `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT   castID,
         COUNT(*) AS Cnt
FROM     atable
GROUP BY castID
ORDER BY Cnt DESC
LIMIT    1
;
```

However, if there can be ties, the above query would return only one row. If you want all the "winners", you could take the count from the above query as a scalar result and compare it against all the counts to return only those that match:

```
SELECT   castID,
         COUNT(*) AS Cnt
FROM     atable
GROUP BY castID
HAVING   COUNT(*) = (
                        SELECT   COUNT(*)
                        FROM     atable
                        GROUP BY castID
                        ORDER BY Cnt DESC
                        LIMIT    1
                    )
;
```

(Basically, same as [Charles Bretana's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23464290/297408), it just derives the top count differently.)

Alternatively, you could use a variable  to rank all the counts and then return only those that have the ranking of 1:

```
SELECT castID,
       Cnt
FROM   (
          SELECT   castID,
                   COUNT(*) AS Cnt,
                   @r := IFNULL(@r, 0) + 1 AS r
          FROM     atable
          GROUP BY castID
          ORDER BY Cnt DESC
       ) AS s
WHERE r = 1
;
```

Please note that with the above method the variable must either not exist or be pre-initialised with a 0 or NULL prior to running the query. To be on the safe side, you could initialise the variable directly in your query:

```
SELECT s.castID,
       s.Cnt
FROM   (SELECT @r := 0) AS x
CROSS JOIN
       (
          SELECT   castID,
                   COUNT(*) AS Cnt,
                   @r := @r + 1 AS r
          FROM     atable
          GROUP BY castID
          ORDER BY Cnt DESC
       ) AS s
WHERE s.r = 1
;
```